# A simple Python program to study classes

Tags: python-3.x, class

For the sake of studying the concept of classes in Python, I have written a program which is meant to calculate the average of a tuple of numbers. However, the program returns an error message which is quoted.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""
Python program to calculate the average value of
a set of integers or float numbers.
Input format: a tuple, e.g. (1,2,3)

When run, the program generates an error message in line 27
"""

class Mean_value():
    def __init__(self, operand):
        self.operand = operand

    def calculate_average(self, operand):
        self.operand = operand

        all_in_all = sum(operand)
        nmbr       = len(operand)
        average    = all_in_all/nmbr

        self.average = average
        return self.average

        operand = input("Key in numbers as a tuple: ")
        print(operand)  #temp, the operand is taken in by the program

x = Mean_value.calculate_average(operand)  #line 27

print(x)
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\Exercise76a.py", line 27, in <module>
x = Mean_value.calculate_average(operand)
TypeError: calculate_average() missing 1 required positional argument: 'operand'
```

I would highly appreciate any hints from members more experienced than myself.

Comment: Show us how you create and object of this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The program contains comments**

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    """
    The program computes the average value of a sequence of positive integers,
    keyed in as a tuple.

    After entering the tuple, the input function returns a string,
    e.g.(1,2,3) (tuple) --> (1,2,3) (string).
    On screen the two objects look the same.

    The major code block deals with reversing the type of the input,
    i.e. string --> tuple,
    e.g. (1,2,3) (string) --> (1,2,3) (tuple).

    The maths is dealt with by the class Average.
    """
    class Average:
       def __init__(self, tup):
           self.tup = tup

       def calculate(self):
           return sum(self.tup)/len(self.tup)

    """Major code block begins ----------"""

    #create containers
    L_orig_lst = []
    S_str = ""

    print("The program computes the average value of")
    print("a sequence of positive integers, input as a tuple.\n")

    #in orig_str store the string-type of the tuple keyed in
    orig_str = input("Key in the numbers as a tuple:\n")

    lnth = len(orig_str)

    #copy each character from orig_str into the list L_orig_lst (the original list)
    for i in range(lnth):
        if orig_str[i] in ['(', '.', ',' , ')', '1', '2', '3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']:

            #if one of the characters left parenthesis, period, comma, right parenthesis or a digit
            #is found in orig_str, then S_str is extended with that character
            S_str = S_str + orig_str[i]
            L_orig_lst.append(S_str)

            #set S_str to be empty
            S_str = ""

        elif orig_str[i] == " ":
            pass
        else:
            print("Error in input")
            break

    #at this stage the following transformation has taken place,
    #tuple (string) --> tuple (list)
    #e.g. (1,2,3) (string) --> ['(' , '1' , ',' , '2' , ',' , '3' , ')'], L_orig_lst

    #create new container
    #and set S_str to be empty
    L_rev_lst = []
    S_str = ""

    lnth = len(L_orig_lst)

    #from the original list, L_orig_lst, copy those elements which are digits (type string)
    #and append them to the revised list, L_rev_lst.
    for i in range(lnth):
        if L_orig_lst[i] in ['1', '2', '3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']:

            #if the element in the original list is a digit (type string),
            #then extend S_str with this element
            S_str = S_str + L_orig_lst[i]

        elif L_orig_lst[i] == ',':
            #if the element in the original list is a comma, then finalize the reading of the number,
            #convert the current number (type string) into an integer
            S_int = int(S_str)

            #and append the integer to the revised list
            L_rev_lst.append(S_int)

            #set S_str to be empty
            S_str = ""
        else:
            pass

    #also convert the last number (type string) to an integer,
    S_int = int(S_str)

    #and also append the last integer to the revised list
    L_rev_lst.append(S_int)

    #now convert the revised list into a tuple
    T_tpl = tuple(L_rev_lst)

    """Major code block ends --------"""

    #calculate the average for the tuple T_tpl
    #call the class
    x = Average(T_tpl)

    #instantiate the class
    y = x.calculate()
    print("Average value: ", y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any method in your class with `self` as the first parameter is an *instance method*, meaning it's supposed to be called on an instance *of* the class and not on the class itself.

In other words, the `self` parameter isn't just for show. When you do this:

```
x = Mean_value(operand)
x.calculate_average(operand)
```

the python interpreter actually takes `x` and passes it through to the function as the first parameter (i.e. `self`). Hence, when you try to call `calculate_average()` on the class `Mean_value` instead of on an object *of that type*, it only passes one of the two required parameters (there's no instance to pass automatically as `self`, so it just passes the one argument you've given it, leaving the second argument unspecified).

If you want to have a method be static (called on the class instead of on an instance of the class), you should use the `@staticmethod` decorator on the method in question, and omit the `self` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this error is to make your `calculate_average` method static. Like this:

```
@staticmethod
def calculate_average(operand):
    # but be careful here as you can't access properties with self here.
     all_in_all = sum(operand)
     nmbr       = len(operand)
     average    = all_in_all/nmbr
     return average
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion, except for the fact, that I didn't add the  headline  you suggest, @staticmethod.-is this required for static methods ?

Comment: yes, it's required. without @staticmethod annotation, Python wouldn't know it's a static method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried adding the headline, but to no avail. ..I must find out a way of showing you the code...I use Windows and will try with Notepad.

Comment: I'm afraid it wasn't possible to send the code as a comment in Notepad.

Comment: I have developed the program so that it no longer 
generates error messages, but doesn't produce 
the wanted result either.

I use IDLE as my IDE for Python.
It seems that repl.it also can be used as an IDE, 
but to me it appears to be a community outside of Stackoverflow.

However, the current issue is, how does one,
within the frames of Stackoverflow, respond with
both program code and text comments.